# Verify program calls with gtest & gmock

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I'm using google mock & google test and I have an object such as:

```
  class Foo {
    public :
        Foo(){}

        virtual void method(int arg) {
            int var = a(arg) ;
            if (var<5){
                b() ;
            }
        }

        virtual int a(int arg){
            // do stuff
        }

        virtual int b(){
            // do stuff
        }
}
```

I want to check that a() is called one time and b() is not whenever a failed ( = return a value <5)
So I wrote something like:

```
MockFoo mock ;

mock.method(badArg);

EXPECT_CALL(
    mock,
    a
)
.Times(1) ;

EXPECT_CALL(
    mock,
    a
)
.Times(0) ;
```

But gtest tell me that none of those methods are called, what should I use?

Thanks for your explainations

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ my bad, I fixed it

Comment: is it possible to post your solution for the benefit of others who search?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon I meant that I fixed the typo, not the problem, this part of the topic remain unsolved..

Comment: You need to put your `EXPECT_CALL` before you call to `method`, e.g. first setup your expectations and then do whatever should fulfill those expectations. There are other problems in your code as well (`a` should return something, right?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use gmock properly, you need to set up your expectation **before** you run the real thing. This way, gmock knows what's coming and will be able to analyze if the real stuff really meets requirements. Otherwise, if you call the function before you set up your expectations, it's like asking a catcher to get into his standby position after you throw the ball. The catcher off course will miss.

In your case, you want something like:

```
MockFoo mock ;

// Catchers ready!
EXPECT_CALL(mock, a)
    .Times(1) ;
EXPECT_CALL(mock, b)
    .Times(0) ;

// Here's the ball!!
mock.method(watermelon);
```